# $x+y> \epsilon$ then $x>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or $y>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Tags: probability

Since the statement is true,

$P(x+y>\epsilon) \le P(x>\frac{\epsilon}{2} \text{ or } y>\frac{\epsilon}{2})$

Why the inequality exists there?

Comment: Which of the four inequalities in your statement are you confused by the existence of?

Comment: $\le$ this one!

Comment: See the monotonicity property of probability.

Comment: Sometimes $x>\epsilon/2$ but $y$ is so low that $x+y\le\epsilon$.  That increases the right-hand side, but not the left-hand side, so the right-hand side might be greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement 
$$x+y > \epsilon \Longrightarrow x > \frac \epsilon 2 \ \text{ or } \ y > \frac \epsilon 2$$ 
is equivalent to 
$$\{ x+y > \epsilon \} \subseteq \{  x > \frac \epsilon 2 \} \cup \{  y > \frac \epsilon 2 \}.$$
The latter set contains the former so the probability that it occurs is bigger.

Comment: In your last equation it's not necessarily a strict subset is it?

Comment: no indeed I edited

Answer (score 3):

Simply note that $\{x+y>2\varepsilon\} \subseteq \{x > \varepsilon\} \cup \{y > \varepsilon\}$. Then apply monotonicity of probability measure.